# Salesforce Soap API - Update Null Fields

Tags: soap-api, integration

I am using Salesforce Soap API (Version 33). I have created a .Net project and consumed their WSDL file in the project. I want to update a Custom Object using the update command.

The above functionality is working fine.

The only problem I have is that when I update null fields in Salesforce to a new (non-null) value, the fields do not get updated with the new value. Any field having a non-null value prior to the update, gets the updated value.

I want to know if there is flag or a header that needs to be set before calling the update to get around this problem. Any help would be great.

Thanks,
MAli

Comment: Are you using the .net toolkit? Try specify additional "specified" flag for those fields. For an example if you're updating `SObject.CustomField__c`, also specify `SObject.CustomField__cspecified = true;`. See if that works

Comment: I am not using .net tookket. The "SObject.CustomField__cspecified = true;" works :) . Thanks Bachovski

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the fields based on their type are not part of the SOAP message and you need to explicitly specify that by appending the `specified` keyword to the field

`SObject.CustomField__cspecified = true`

In order to ensure that the field will be a part of the SOAP message. I still haven't seen official documentation around this - I discovered it the hard way :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did not find any documentation as well for "Specified" attribute. I am using the Enterprise WSDL, so I might need add an extra line of code per field.

Comment: That's right, for each field that's causing dramas, you'll need to do the above.