# Why is date/number/boolean data type ignored for create using Enterprise WSDL

Tags: soap, enterprise, enterprise-wsdl

I have shared enterprise wsdl with the 3rd party team. This is being used to create record in CRM. I am able to create a record with all the fields using SOAP UI and the credentials being shared with 3rd Party. But when the team tried to create a records, a record is created in CRM but all the date/number/boolean are null.

I have checked FLS and also tested the same using SOAP UI. SOAP UI does not ignore date/number/boolean. System is based in sharepoint.

Any idea guys?

Comment: It would appear that there is something wrong with the SOAP payload coming out of the 3rd party system. Can you get a sample of the raw request? I'd compare them with your SOAP UI calls and [Force.com SOAP API Sample WSDL Structures](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/salesforce-soap-api-sample-wsdls.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is that they aren't setting the "Specified" properties that go with each field in the Enterprise API when it is proxied into a .NET project.

If you look at the complex type for Account in the Enterprise WSDL it will have:

```
<element name="AnnualRevenue" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:double"/>
```

Note how it is both nillable (could be set to null) and has a minOccurs or zero (could be completely omitted).

In the proxy object for Account you get a corresponding property:

```
public System.Nullable<double> AnnualRevenue { get; set; }
```

So you might assume you could set that field value with something like:

```
EnterpriseApi.Account acc = new EnterpriseApi.Account();
acc.AnnualRevenue = 100.0; 
//... send the Account to Salesforce
```

But, as you've found, that isn't sufficient to actually set/change the AnnualRevenue field.

The problem is that when dealing with a field that can be null or completely ommited .NET didn't know if you wanted to clear that field out or actually set it to null.

So to compensate for that an additional "Specified" property is generated:

```
 public bool AnnualRevenueSpecified { get; set; }
```

You need to set the field to true. Both if you want to send through an actual value or null. E.g.

```
EnterpriseApi.Account acc = new EnterpriseApi.Account();
acc.AnnualRevenue = 100.0; 
acc.AnnualRevenueSpecified = true;
//... send the Account to Salesforce
```

See also:

- [Salesforce Soap API - Update Null Fields](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/73666/102)

Comment: I just figured out this out and then came the answer. Boom !!. Thanks a lot :)